# Should I change one spark plug and wire or all of them?

Tags: ford, sparkplugs

2 days ago I felt that something isn't right with my Ford. A mechanic told me that he wants to replace all four spark plugs and wires but could I just change the one?

I'm scared that he's ripping me off please help!

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but I wonder if plugs and wires are the way to go here. On what basis is the mechanic suggesting this?

Comment: If your satisfied with my response could you hit the little green check next to it?  I like the ego points it give me.  lol   Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Fear not, he's not ripping you off.  Spark plugs are cheap, you change them in sets as you do with brakes or spark plug wires.

***You want all of your spark plugs to match and have nearly the same levels of electrical resistance as all of the other plugs.***

This make the engine run smoothly.  If you had one spark plug firing properly and three that were not you could damage your engine as it would be a bit out of balance.

You want balance in your engine.  You want balance with combustion.  This gives you efficiency and as well, longevity, with your motor.

This is standard maintenance.  I don't think anyone on this site would only change one spark plug on their own vehicle.

**Exhale.**

It's fine.       :-)

Best of luck.

Comment: It would be worth clarifying whether the same conclusion is applicable for coil-over-plug configurations (so no wires)

Comment: Well answered. When changing parts like that you want harmony throughout the working components within your engine. It's common practice to replace plugs and wires in sets.

Comment: @Zaid   You had to go there!  LOL

Comment: Of course I did :) Or should we post that up as a separate question?

Comment: I think you should.  I tried tried to find a dupe but couldn't.  Doesn't mean there isn't one though.  I've been up all night working and am getting a little loopy.  It's a good question though, worthy of it's own space.

Comment: So is it necessary to change the leads as well? I'ts quite pricey and I'd like to save some money

Comment: I look at spark plugs and spark plug wires as consumable items, like paper towels.  It's a good idea to do so from time to time.  The wire can have from 5,000 to 50,000 volts running through them.  From electrical theory you are potentially carbonizing the copper within the wire.  This increases electrical resistance and makes it harder to have a good spark over time.  You can avoid the extra cost and not do it but you will potentially retain the problem you have and not fix it.  Imagine, 50,000 volts 3,500 RPM average.  2 hours daily drive time.  420,000 sparks per wire per day.  :)

Comment: Fun fact: many plug wires don't actually contain any wire at all.  They use a compressed carbon impregnated fiber which purposely has a high resistance. [Plug wire types](http://shop.advanceautoparts.com/o/article-spark-plug-wires-basics).  I cut apart some old wires to see what was inside and was _shocked_ to not find any wire.

Comment: It's not necessary to change the leads and it's not necessary to change all of them if you do. But it's often a good idea. If you're tight on money - just change whatever absolutely needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how it went for me. One morning, truck wouldn’t start, just kept turning over. It was 5 degrees out. I replaced one plug only. Truck started right up. Another issue I had was bucking on the highway. That still remained. When the weather warmed up I tackled the other plugs and wires as well. Got all but one. It was frozen. The truck ran great for about 20 minutes. Then worse than ever before. I sprayed the frozen plug with PB blaster the day before. That morning, got a good bite on it, turned counter clockwise, then clockwise a few times and went for it. It broke free. Swapped it out with the last motorcraft spark plug. Didn’t check gap. Swapped out the coil pack. Truck is running great with 200,000 miles on it. Not sure if it ran worse because I had one inferior plug and wire that wouldn’t jive with the rest or if it needed the coil pack as well. Also. Cut the hard to fish wires at the coil pack and duct tape it to the new one. It’ll save you 20 minutes as opposed to fishing it thru by hand. Good luck. Hope this helps